# How to extract all text before comma, period, or colin from a website using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to split up the two address lines into 2 different variables when extracting from the website, but some of the locations only have 1 address. I found that usually there is a comma, colin, or period separating the two address lines. I am extracting all of the locations, and that website is an example of a location that has two address lines. In this case, address 1 would be 2 Hemlock Rd. and the second address would be PO Box 904. In other instances where there is not 2 addresses, address 2 should be empty.

This is the website:https://www.winmar.ca/find-a-location/#267

And this is the Python code, as well as the html for the website.

```
location_address1 = soup.select_one(f"[data-id='{num}'] .heading:contains('Address') + p").contents[0].strip()
location_address2 = ','.join(location_address1.split(',|.|:')[1:]) 
<p>
2 Hemlock Rd. PO Box 904
<br>
Corner Brook, NL
<br>
A2H 6J2
</p>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem. This shows your gratitude to the user and helps other solve similar problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select better your HTML here is the solution. I've used CSS Selector, since it's more accurate; because there is no xPath on beautifoulSoup. After getting everything we need to convert object to text, then work around available content; then here is where we split the lines and remove line breaks for better indent.

> Note: This has been tested and runs correctly.

Run code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.winmar.ca/find-a-location/#267")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

address = soup.select('#box-309 > div:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(5)')

text = address[0].get_text()
print(text)
```

Outputs:

```
 358 Keltic Drive Sydney River ,NS B1R 1V7
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. In this case, there is no second address, but in my example, PO Box 904 would be the second address.

Comment: then just remove the split... and you will get a full address. I've updated the code please check.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the second line address, which only some of the locations have. The location you are working with does not have a second address, so preferably, the second address would be blank. In my example location, there is a second address, which is the PO Box, so that would be the second address. Sorry for responding late.

Comment: you want to get only NS B1R 1V7 from the address right? from this output ???

Comment: NS is the province, and B1R 1V7 is the postal code. The location you have picked does not have a second address. In the example I gave, there is a second address, which is the PO box. Thanks. The output would be Address 1: 2 Hemlock Rd. PO Box 904.

Comment: if this is the case you should add a regular expression if all of them are in the same format. it's easier to handle it that way...

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the length of lines and parse the text into variable accordingly. see example below.

```
num = 267
location_address = soup.select_one(f"[data-id='{num}'] .heading:contains('Address') + p")
print(location_address)

#Determine the number of address lines
print(len(location_address.find_all('br')))

TotalLines = len(location_address.find_all('br'))
line1 =''
line2=''
if TotalLines >1:
    line1 = location_address.contents[0]
    line2 = location_address.contents[2]
else:
    line1 = location_address.contents[0]

print('Address Line1:',line1)
print('Address Line2:',line2)
```

Output:

Address Line1: 
2 Hemlock Rd. PO Box 904
Address Line2: 
Corner Brook, NL

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. PO Box 904 is supposed to be the second address.

Comment: What you have given me as the second address is the province and city.